# What is the most efficient way to sum across tuples that are themselves within a tuple (iterable of an iterable)?

Tags: python, performance, tuples, python-itertools

I am, essentially, generating a tuple of tuples:

```
import datetime
import csv

from itertools import product, combinations, chain

part_1 = {
    'a':{2,1,0},
    'b':{3,4,5},
    'c':{7,8,9},
    'd':{10,11,12}      
}

sorted_part_1 = sorted(part_1)
result = product(*(part_1[Thing] for Thing in sorted_part_1))

# for a in result:
#   print('comb a' + str(a))

comb_list_total = it.combinations(result,4)
```

(Though with several orders more permutations.)

What I'd like to do is to sum each tuple/iterable, eg `((2, 5, 9, 11), (2, 5, 9, 12), (2, 5, 7, 10), (2, 5, 7, 11))` --> `(8,20,32,44)`

(What I'd actually like to do is to THEN get the difference between that aggregated tuple and a pre-defined tuple say, (50,50,50,50) -> (32,30,18,6) and, finally, sum that difference to identify which tuple of tuples maximizes/minimizes that aggregated difference.)

How can I perform this math on the tuples, and efficiently map the result to the original tuple?

Comment: would you mind using pandas/numpy?

Comment: Since the tuples you're summing over are combinatorially generated, I would look for a mathematical way to simplify the sum without having to explicitly compute it. If we're able to count how many times each combination from the `product` should appear in the result, then we can multiply instead of adding; likewise if we can count how many times each number from `part_1` should appear in the overall sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prerequisites:

```
iterable_of_tuples = [
    (...),  # tuple 1
    (...),  # tuple 2
    ...
    (...)   # tuple N
]
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

sum_of_all_tuples = tuple(sum(np.array(t) for t in iterable_of_tuples))
```

Pure Python (might be less efficient on long iterables):

```
sum_of_all_tuples = tuple(map(sum, zip(*iterable_of_tuples))))
```